# Spring WebClient obtains access token on every request to resource server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am writing an unsecured REST api which is itself a client to another OAuth2 secured backend resource server. The configuration is working in that I can make a call to the secured resource. However, logging tells me that a token is being requested on every WebClient call. I expected that the access token would be obtained once, and then presented again on subsequent calls. Is there a problem with my configuration? Can anyone help to get this working so that access tokens are only obtained when necessary, not on every request?

I have configured my application (Spring Boot 3.1, WebFlux) like so:

**pom.xml**

```
spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client
spring-boot-starter-webflux
lombok
spring-boot-starter-test
reactor-test
spring-security-test
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.salesforce.authorization-grant-type=client_credentials
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.salesforce.client-id=xxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.salesforce.client-secret=xxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.salesforce.token-uri=https://my.idp.com/services/oauth2/token

logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
logging.level.reactor.netty.http.client=DEBUG
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.authorizeExchange((exchange) -> {
            exchange.anyExchange().permitAll();
        });
        http.oauth2Login(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

**WebClientConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {

    @Bean
    WebClient getClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations, ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClients)
    {
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth =
                new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientRegistrations, authorizedClients);

        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("salesforce");

        return WebClient
                .builder()
                .filter(oauth)
                .build();
    }

}
```

**SalesforceController.java**

```
@RestController
// @Slf4j  // Lombok logging
public class SalesforceController {

    private final WebClient webClient;

    public SalesforceController(WebClient webClient) {
        this.webClient = webClient;
    }

    @GetMapping(value="/order", produces="application/json")
    Mono<String> getOrder(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("salesforce") OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient)
    {

        Mono<String> result = this.webClient
                .get()
                .uri("https://my.service.com/Order/1")
                .attributes(oauth2AuthorizedClient(authorizedClient))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5));

        return result;

    }
}
```

**ControllerTests.java**

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient(timeout = "10000")
@Slf4j // lombok
public class ControllerTests {

    @Autowired WebTestClient webClient;

    @Test
    void order() throws Exception
    {
        String result = this.webClient.get().uri("/order").exchange().expectStatus().isOk().returnResult(String.class).getResponseBody().blockFirst();
        log.info(result);
        // Expect this second call to reuse the access token obtained from the previous call!
        result = this.webClient.get().uri("/order").exchange().expectStatus().isOk().returnResult(String.class).getResponseBody().blockFirst();
        log.info(result);
    }
}
```